# Reverting local changes to a file using GItPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

**Is there a way under the [GitPython](http://gitorious.org/git-python) library to revert local changes to a single file?**

Under the Git command line I would just use `git checkout filename` but attempting to do this under the GitPython API, like so

```
repo.index.checkout([filename])
```

leads to the following error,

> git.exc.CheckoutError: Some files could not be checked out from the index due to local modifications:['foo']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, figured it out a few minutes after posting by looking at the [source](http://gitorious.org/git-python/mainline/blobs/master/git/index/base.py#line913).

If I turn on force by using `repo.index.checkout([filename]. force=True)` it works fine.

There may be a better way, but according to the source the force parameter is just there to overwrite local changes.

> :param force:
>           If True, existing files will be overwritten even if they contain local modifications.
>           If False, these will trigger a CheckoutError.